# How to launch an android service from a custom call number

Tags: android, service, ussd, background-service

I'm developing an Android application, i have a service running in background that i want to    lauch it by introducing a **custom ussd number**. For example when i call **#*12345*#** my service starts.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest that listens for `android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE` intents. You also specify the secret code in the manifest.

For example, this manifest entry registers `MyBroadcastReceiver` for the secret code `*#*#12345#*#*`.

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"/>
        <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="12345"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`MyBroadcastReceiver` should look something like this:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Create an intent to start your Service.
    }
}
```